# How to change the installed version of a nested global npm package?

Tags: npm

For one of the globally installed npm packages I use, one of the dependencies received a minor version upgrade that unfortunately introduces breaking changes. In the below output, amplify-codegen version 2.28.**1** was installed. When executing the command previously, amplify-codegen 2.28.**0** would be installed.

```
npm i -g @aws-amplify/cli@6.4.0
npm list -g amplify-codegen
└─┬ @aws-amplify/cli@6.4.0
  ├── amplify-codegen@2.28.1
  ├─┬ amplify-provider-awscloudformation@4.65.0
  │ └── amplify-codegen@2.28.1 deduped
```

Here the problem is that, despite the update from 2.28.0 to 2.28.1 being a minor version update, it introduces changes that break our project. So we would like to revert the update, and ensure that when installing @aws-amplify/cli@6.4.0, the 2.28.0 version of amplify-codegen is installed.

For a locally installed package, this could be easily resolved with a yarn.lock or the "overrides" option in the package.json. However, for globally installed packages, I'm struggling to find a solution, as there's no equivalent of a yarn.lock or package.json for globally installed npm packages.